# How do I link two custom OCaml modules with `corebuild`

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have two OCaml modules, namely nhc.ml and test.ml. Both of these modules reference parser.mly, scanner.mll and ast.mli.

The goal is to have one executable, namely nhc.native, where I can still reference the functions of test.ml.

```
./nhc.native fun_from_test
```

Separating the two modules separately works:

```
corebuild nhc.native  
corebuild test.native
```

But when I try to use corebuild to link the two as follows:

```
corebuild nhc.native -mod test
```

I get the error:

```
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
     Scanner referenced from test.cmx
     Parser referenced from test.cmx
```

If I run the same command, without first mkaing the test executable (test.native), I get the following error:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Cannot find file test.cmx
```

How can I get the specified functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do the following with the compiler. But an alternative solution was to just open the module inside nhc.ml as follows:

```
open Test
```

and I get the behavior I wanted.